# Difference between .Where(filter expression).FirstOrDefault() and .FirstOrDefault(filter expression)

Tags: c#, entity-framework

in Entity Framework, what is the difference in doing:

```
db.Table.Where(filter).FirstOrDefault()
```

or

```
db.Table.FirstOrDefault(filter)
```

I guess that the first one applies the filter first and then take the first record. The second one get all records from table and then apply the filter, being more inefficient. Can you confirm me if this is correct or both are equivalent?

Best regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These two have the same performance both in memory and in EF.

In memory, the first one obtains the results lazily, so it is not materially slower than the second one.

In EF or LINQ2SQL the query gets converted to SQL in its entirety, so only one result gets selected from the database in both instances. To see what is going on, [enable SQL logging in EF](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1412902/335858), and observe that the generated SQL is identical.

The code with a separate `Where` is more typing, though, so the second form is preferred.

Answer (score 7):

There is none. They are equivalent.

Generally, though, you should keep the chaining to a minimum. Therefore the second is considered "correct".

Comment: I'm not so sure - it would be good to see some diagnostics of what EF is doing. It the filter can 'pushed to the DB' then the first form might be more efficient.

Comment: @n8wrl - The diagnostics have been done (they were proven out long ago) and it has been proven that both generate the same query.

Comment: @n8wrl The filter is pushed to the DB in both cases, or neither, depending on whether the filter can be translated at all.